# OTP encoded polyline same as Google encoded polyline?

Tags: google-maps, polyline, google-polyline, opentripplanner

I have been researching and trying to make sense. My question: are the encoded polylines that Google gives in its directions api same as the leg geometry encoded polylines of Open Trip Planner?

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but yes, Open Trip Planner returns google Encoded Polyline format.
You can check this link for reference
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opentripplanner-dev/kuR6fM3fY7I