# API Google Maps doesn't return enough of step

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, direction

I'm making an app with Xamarin.Forms.Maps and then, I need to get all of the steps between two "place id" to make my own polyline. However, when I'm making my request, I get about only thirty five steps.

35 steps.. Between Le Mans (France) and Paris (France).. About 200km but only 35 steps.. The problem isn't that the two points aren't connected to the polyline made, no, the problem is that the polyline get out of the existing road..

Google API direction seems to give me, only, some important information, like important steps, but without following the road.. Does it normal?

PS: This is my request (I use Postman to test it)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Le Mans&destination=Paris&key=[MY_API_KEY]&travel_mode=DRIVING
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the `polyline` results in each driving step?

I used your example and got 31 `start_location` that each contain [Encoded Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) for drawing that path on the map.

#### The "Take the exit toward Paris-Centre Porte de Bercy" step results in:

```
"polyline": {
   "points": "mn_iHmxqM@[?WA_@Ck@CeAAMGcAEi@Gc@Ke@GUI[IYGSIMIKGECAMIMEA?EAA?A?K?I@A?C?IBE@C@?@C@GBOHEHGJIVIX_@j@"
 },
```

#### Decoded that is:

[image]

The **"Take the exit on the left onto Bd Périphérique"** step results in 91 points, etc...

There are hundreds and hundreds of locations points within the results, you just have to decode the locations of each driving step and plot them:

[Google's Interactive Poly Line Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility)

Comment: Ho ok thank for this answer, I didn't understand the polyline variable. I thought it was the encoded start/end location of the step.

Comment: @MaximeGuittet here is one @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/3852420/4984832 Lots of others in C# around the web ;-)

Comment: @MaximeGuittet Does that help you enough to plot all the points?

Comment: Ho ok thank for this answer, I didn't understand the polyline variable. I thought it was the encoded start/end location of the step. I just took a look at your link, does it exists a way to decode it? [This link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm#example) show how it's encoded, so I can do it "in the reserved way", but if something easier exists, it would be really nice ^^

Comment: Haha yep, one more time you helped me ;)

Comment: If Encode() "Decode", it's a bit weird to call a function like it ^^ My last question then is, how can I call the method? Polyline is a string in the API response, the method wait an IEnumerable<GeoLocation>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111784/discussion-between-maxime-guittet-and-sushihangover).

Comment: Look at the `Decode` method @ https://gist.github.com/shinyzhu/4617989 That will give you the reverse (string to location coords)