# Polylines draws a straight line between two points in Google Maps

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin, directions

I am incorporate Google Maps V2 in my project and I am trying to get the driving direction between the two positions:

```
List<Position> RouteCoordinates = new List<Position>();
RouteCoordinates.Add(new Position(37.7850268, -122.4005109));
RouteCoordinates.Add(new Position(37.780624, -122.390541));

var polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
polylineOptions.InvokeColor(0x66FF0000);

foreach (var position in RouteCoordinates)
{
    polylineOptions.Add(new LatLng(position.Latitude, position.Longitude));

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
    marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(position.Latitude, position.Longitude));
    gmap.AddMarker(marker);
}

gmap.AddPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

But this draws a straight line between the two points... Is there any method to get the driving directions between these two points?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189634/api-google-maps-doesnt-return-enough-of-step/37191234#37191234

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425499/how-to-draw-interactive-polyline-on-route-google-maps-v2-android