# How to draw route line from start location to end location in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maps

I am new in Xamarin. I wanted to draw a route / path / road line (and not a straight line) from start location to end location. I followed [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/polyline-map-overlay), but this results in straight lines between locations and not the path. After searching for more info, I got a [sample for Xamarin.iOS](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100288/how-to-draw-a-line-in-maps-between-two-points-but-in-walking-mode). I am looking for similar solution in Xamarin.forms which can run on both Android and iOS. I used xamarin.forms.maps nuget package manager.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189634/api-google-maps-doesnt-return-enough-of-step/37191234#37191234

Comment: @SushiHangover I followed your link and I with the help of following answer in the forum, I was able to solve my query. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92565/android-ionmapreadycallback-forms-2-3-4